# How to avoid double dot in Theorem Head Spec in case of theorem with no name?

Tags: theorems, punctuation, amsthm

I'm using the `\newtheoremstyle{name}` command to generate a specific theorem head spec in the form of:

```
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}.\thmnote{ #3}}
```

where `#1` is **Theorem**, `#2` is 'the theorem number', and `#3` is 'my theorem name'.

However, when I don't use 'my theorem name' as in some cases, the output gives two dots (the one after `\thmnumber`, and the one after the `thm` head).

How can I avoid this? I mean, how to avoid the extra dot in case of a theorem with no name?

Comment: @: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to mark your inline code as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move the dot into the argument of `\thmnote`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {3pt}{3pt}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{. #3}}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[name]
text
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
text
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it was trivial but I didn't see it!