# "case" situation to avoid double periods when using newcommand with a period

Tags: macros, luatex

Shown is a MWE (from M. Scharrer's package actually) that highlights my question.

Sometimes I invoke a `newcommand` in the middle of a sentence, and sometimes at the end. The `newcommand` outputs a 'period', and I want to automatically avoid having a double period if it winds up on the end of a sentence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand{\aname}{Some Co.}
\begin{document}
I enjoy working at \aname{}.

She worked at \aname{} for 5 years.

\vspace{4mm}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

which outputs the following:

[image]

The lorem text is irrelevant...

Searching on the internet revealed this: [How to avoid double dot in Theorem Head Spec in case of theorem with no name?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/how-to-avoid-double-dot-in-theorem-head-spec-in-case-of-theorem-with-no-name) but it would "always be at the end" I guess.

Looking for a "case" kind of choice led me to [how to choose only one situation by conditional cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371664/how-to-choose-only-one-situation-by-conditional-cases) but it seems way overkill for my case...

Maybe the `ifthen` package...?

I forgot to mention this one, which looks promising, but I am still trying to understand it. [How to peek and test whether the next character is a digit?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323311/how-to-peek-and-test-whether-the-next-character-is-a-digit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to append the period only if a period does not follow (with a possible `{}` in between) and if a period doesn't follow, there should also be `\@`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\appendperiod}{%
  \futurelet\next\append@period
}
\newcommand\append@period{%
  \if\noexpand\next\bgroup
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  \append@period@after@gobble
  \append@@period
}
\newcommand\append@@period{%
  \if\noexpand\next.\else.\@\fi
}
\newcommand\append@period@after@gobble[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\appendperiod
  \else
    .\@{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\aname}{Some Co\appendperiod}

\begin{document}

I enjoy working at \aname{}. Good.

I enjoy working at \aname. Good

Do I enjoy working at \aname{}?

Do I enjoy working at \aname?

She worked at Some Co.\@ for 5 years. % to check the space after the period

She worked at \aname{} for 5 years.

She used to work at \aname, but now she's retired.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This sort of thing has a nasty habit of going wrong when the macro appears in a situation that has not been considered (there always seems to be at least one). Still...

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\aname{Some Co\@ifnextchar{.}{}{.\ }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
I enjoy working at \aname. I really do.

She worked at \aname for 5 years.
\end{document}
```

The idea here is that when `\@ifnextchar` sees a full stop it does nothing; otherwise it produces a full stop followed by a space.

Comment: Simple, succinct, and applicable with other things... great! Interesting, too, that you don't use the `\aname{}`, but instead the `\aname`... Thankfully just discovered `texdoc sources2e` (if I can understand it...)

Comment: What about `She used to work at \aname, but now she's retired.`?

Comment: I think this will work... but maybe not very robust....   `\newcommand\aname{Some Co\@ifnextchar{,}{}{\@ifnextchar{.}{}{.\ } }}
`